# Gettin an error with custom alertdialog onbackpress

Tags: android, back, android-alertdialog

I want to exit my app with an my customized alert dialog showing first to ask if user is sure they want to exit.  am getting an error with the code I have below. By the way I used getparent() since the activity is within an activity group:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grocerylistdelete, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
        builder.setView(view);

        Button yes = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
        yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();    

            }
        });

        Button no = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);
        no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecipeList.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


            }

    }
```

Here is the error in LogCat:

```
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.mexican.recipes.RecipeList.onBackPressed(RecipeList.java:139)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at   android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:1898)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1280)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2078)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1663)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1687)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1120)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2073)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1663)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchKeyEvent(TabHost.java:278)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1687)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1120)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2073)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1663)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2560)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2535)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1867)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-01 11:45:39.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT:
Here is the whole code for RecipeList.java:

```
public class RecipeList extends ListActivity{
Typeface font;
Typeface bold;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipelist);

    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(RecipeList.this.getAssets(), "Book Antiqua.ttf");

    TextView recipe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewrecipe);

    recipe.setTypeface(font, Typeface.BOLD);
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(RecipeList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.textViewCategory,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories)));
        this.getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);



}
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipelistrow, parent, false);
    String [] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);


    ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewRecipe);
    TextView tvCategory = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);
    TextView tvCategoryDesc = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewcategorydesc);

    tvCategory.setTypeface(font, Typeface.BOLD);
    tvCategory.setText(items[position]);

    if(items[position].equals("Burritos")){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_burritos);
        tvCategoryDesc.setText("Burritos, with tasty combination of beef and beans, make it an enticing dish for your family and friends");
    }if(items[position].equals("Tacos")){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_tacos);
        tvCategoryDesc.setText("Taco counts a favorite for its versatility and variety. It's perfect for meat lovers and veggie lovers too!");
    }if(items[position].equals("Enchiladas")){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_enchiladas);
        tvCategoryDesc.setText("Enchilada makes the perfect match for your favorite salsa. Make it a bit spicy. It's awesome!");
    }if(items[position].equals("Fajitas")){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_fajitas);
        tvCategoryDesc.setText("Fajita is well-loved for its exquisite and delightful filling. It's a choice of either beef or boneless chicken.");
    }if(items[position].equals("Quesadillas")){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_quesadillas);
        tvCategoryDesc.setText("Quesadillas are filled with oozing goodness and mouthwatering flavors that you will find it hard to resist.");
    }if(items[position].equals("Salads")){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_salads);
        tvCategoryDesc.setText("Eat healthy and feel healthy with your protein-rich salads. Cut-off your carbs with this Mexican dish.");
    }if(items[position].equals("Chilis")){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_chili);
        tvCategoryDesc.setText("Make an extraordinary appetizer out of your chili con carne and enjoy its tempting flavors.");
    }if(items[position].equals("Other Delicacies")){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_otherdelicacies);
        tvCategoryDesc.setText("Learn more about the Mexican recipes that are sinfully good!");
    }
    return row;

    }
}
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SubRecipeList.class);
        i.putExtra("id", id);


        View view = TabGroupActivity.group.getLocalActivityManager()
                .startActivity("show_city", i
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();


                TabGroupActivity.group.replaceView(view);



    }

    public void grocerylist (View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecipeList.this, GroceryList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void recipe (View v){

        Intent i = new Intent(RecipeList.this, RecipeList.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void more (View v){

        Intent i = new Intent(RecipeList.this, MoreApps.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grocerylistdelete, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
        builder.setView(view);

        Button yes = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
        yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();    

            }
        });

        Button no = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);
        no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecipeList.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


            }

    }
```

Comment: the error is in RecipeList.java, could you please post the relevant code containing line no.139.

Comment: can you specify which is line 139.

Comment: i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: sorry. my bad.. this is line 139.. yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: is your id _buttonYes_ registered in the xml file?

Comment: yes it is. also buttonNo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
```

with

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivityName.this);
```

Hard to know the problem use dialog in this way..

```
public void showDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(yourActivityName.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.grocerylistdelete);
    dialog.setTitle("Save the changes?");

    dialog.show();
    Button yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
    yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do youur work
        }
    });
    Button no = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);
    no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do your work
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem - I tried this. But the same error occurred. I also tried to use the simple alert dialog where I could use set positive/negative buttons.. I used that together with  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
 and it worked. However, I do not want the default layout for alertdialog. I also wanted to customize the buttons. When I tried to customize it and included this activity to an activity group, the error occurred.

Comment: what is line `RecipeList.java:139` ? make sure `buttonYes` and `buttonNo` exists in `grocerylistdelete` ?

Comment: sorry. my bad.. this is line 139.. yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: same error.. which also points out to .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: Silly me. I found out what was wrong. I needed to create different layout sizes for grocerylistdelete since I already had separate folders for different screen sizes. So you are right... buttonYes and buttonNo was not declared on my other xml layouts for different screen sizes. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

once you have figured out the error in RecipeList.java , try using ALertDialog box as below:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setTitle("Quit")
    .setMessage("Do you really want to quit?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
                       //your code for positive button click

            }
                    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
             //your code for negative button click



        }

    })
    .show();
```

Comment: I am trying to implement a customized alert dialog box. Thank you for your answer but this would not work for me...